# windows smb server file is missing when denied access

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2012-r2, smb2

IN windows server 2012 r2 machine, I created a folder called "share" and and a file named test inside that folder.The file 'test' has read write access for user1 and deny access for user2 in security acls. I enabled windows share for that folder. If I map the share \127.0.0.1\share to a drive using the user credentials user1, I can see the file 'test' in the mapped drive. If I map the same share using the user credentials user2, then folder is empty. Why is this happening? Shouldn't we see the file in user2 credentials mapped drive and get access denied when we try to open the file.

Comment: This is probably (IMHO) a shortcoming on how that portion of the shell is dealing with a network connection.  It can clearly see that there is a folder called test, but that user has no rights to look in it.. specifically in this case, they lack "List folder contents".  Also, the relationship between ntfs permissions and share permissions is complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access Based Enumeration is enabled in the windows server. Thats why the file with deny access is missing when map to a drive via smb.